# Excel count in array with multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I believe that I need an array formula in order to accomplish this task, but I'm not entirely sure.

I need to count the number of records which match 'Cadmium' and are greater than a particular value (0.0005).

Here's an example of how my data is arranged. The real dataset contains thousands more species and rows.

Start cell A1:

```
Cadmium      0.0005
Chromium     0.0100
Copper       0.0010
Cadmium      0.0010
Nickel       0.3
Cadmium      0.0010
```

Thus the formula would be able to filter out cadmium, and those results greater than 0.0005 (i.e. two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [COUNTIFS() Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Cadmium",B:B,">.0005")
```